# Programming a MaxMin Linear Optimization

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, mathematical-optimization, summation

I want to program a function for a two-player game. Basically it's like [this:](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineare_Optimierung_(Spieltheorie)) . Each player has an array of options, and the result of the game is based on both players choices. So heres my most promising approach (i've also played around with `LinearProgramming`, which also works up to a point). `c` is like `Length[x]`. `p[i,j]` is a reference to my database, and gives a value between 0 and 1. It describes the probability of a win for player `x` if he chooses strategy `i` and player `y` chooses strategy `j`.

```
p := {{0.5, 0.7, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.5, 0.6}, {0.7, 0.4, 0.5}}

stratmin[c_, x__] := 
  NMinimize[{Sum[x[[i]]*y[j]*p[i, j], {i, c}, {j, c}], 
   Table[y[j] >= 0, {j, c}], Sum[y[j], {j, c}] == 1}, 
   Table[y[j], {j, c}]]

strat[c_] := 
 NMaximize[{stratmin[c, Table[x[i], {i, c}]], 
  Table[x[i] >= 0, {i, c}], Sum[x[i], {i, c}] == 1}, 
  Table[x[i], {i, c}]]

strat[3]
```

But it doesn't work! As you could have guessed, as I am asking a question here. `NMinimize` doesn't seem to use the `x[i]` as a parameter that `NMaximize` uses. If I program this with `LinearProgramming`, since I've got to "nest" variables in the same way, I've got the same problem. The solution btw. should look smth. like `strat=0.5`; x[1] ca. 0.5, x[2] ca. 0.4, x[3] ca. 0.6.

EDIT:

I looked into your program, and tried to understand and research all parts; had to read through [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5216/Wolfram%20Programming%20Language%20Fundamentals.pdf) and [this](https://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/CoreLanguage/CoreLanguage.pdf) to understand all of the notation; but still dont really get how exactly the solution worked. I've reduced the problem to:

```
testmin[x_] := First[NMinimize[{-x^2 + y, y >= 0}, y]]

testmax := NMaximize[{testmin[x]}, x] 

testmax
```

I don't know whether that is too much too ask, but would you do the minimal necessary correction for that example, too, please? Hopefully that helps me understand the necessary step. Also, if you know of any other good resources or tutorials, I would be thankful.

Comment: There's no link?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineare_Optimierung_(Spieltheorie) Sorry 'bout that. I only found it in german though... but the math is universal.

Comment: Possibly relevant: You use `x[[i]]` (double bracket, that is, `Part`) in one and x[i]` in the other.

Comment: Yeah, buuut I load an array into stratmin, so I think I need the double brackets. Tried it, didn't work unfortunately. As a reference, I'll edit the OP code with given p and c.

Comment: All that's needed directly in `testmin` is a "balck-box" behavior wherein it is only defined for explicitly numeric input. To rectify, first `Clear[testmin]` to discard the existing definition, then replace with `testmin[x_?NumberQ] := First[NMinimize[{-x^2 + y, y >= 0}, y]]`. This is the point of my  `.../; VectorQ[xl, Element[#, Reals] &]` restrictions.

Comment: Oookay... thanks for the quick answer! Works. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes some careful coding to make sure the right values are explicitly numeric at the time they need to be (in the inner optimization). Can be done as below. And there may be better ways, I'm no expert.

```
stratmin[p_ /; MatrixQ[p, Element[#, Reals] &], 
  xlist_List /; VectorQ[xlist, Element[#, Reals] &]] := Module[
   {y, c = Length[p], yvars, min, yvals},
   yvars = Array[y, c]; {min, yvals} = 
    NMinimize[{xlist.p.yvars, Map[# >= 0 &, yvars], 
      Total[yvars] == 1}, yvars];
   {min, yvars /. yvals}
   ] /; Length[p] === Length[p[[1]]] === Length[xlist]


strat[p_ /; MatrixQ[p, Element[#, Reals] &]] := Module[
   {x, c = Length[p], xvars, max, xvals},
   xvars = Array[x, c];
   obj[xl_ /; VectorQ[xl, Element[#, Reals] &]] := 
    First[stratmin[p, xl]];
   {max, xvals} = 
    NMaximize[{obj[xvars], Map[# >= 0 &, xvars], Total[xvars] == 1}, 
     xvars];
   {max, xvars /. xvals, stratmin[p, xvars /. xvals][[2]]}
   ] /; Length[p] === Length[p[[1]]]
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1234567];
c = 4;
p = RandomReal[1, {c, c}];

strat[p]

(* Out[203]= {0.457170468845, {0.823855940951, 0., 0.176144059049, 
  0.}, {1., 0., 0., 0.}} *)
```

This takes a couple of seconds. At `c=8` it is already 14 seconds. So it might not scale as well as you want. Again, there may be better ways to go about this. One thing I note is that I have it coded in a way that manages to miss the fact that each level is a linear program (a message at `c=16` makes that clear). This is almost certainly contributing to slowness and may well also cause suboptimal results. So this should just be viewed as a starting point for further refinement.

--- edit ---

Actually I do not see how to recast the outer level as an LP. And `NMaximize` seems to agree that this is not what it is. For any choice of `x` values the inner optimization is an LP (and is done a bit faster using `FindMinimum` instead of `NMinimize`). The fact that the optimal `y` values are always vertices of the `c`-simplex is just due to this LP nature of the inner problems.

That said, if I am seeing this correctly, you can just iterate over the `c` vertices of `y` vectors, and maximize for `x`.

--- end edit ---

--- edit #2 ---

I was not seeing that last part correctly. Player x has to use a probability vector in such a way that player y cannot make the expected value lower than the maximin. Knowing that a vertex vector will be chosen is not enough for x to resort to the idea put forward above.

--- end edit #2 ---

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Will look at it when I'm home. In the end it'll be asymmetric (as in, x has less options than y), and the range will be 30x60 or something... but thank you for showing that problem; I will try to translate that into a LinearProgramming, which runs much more efficient.

Comment: Wrote an edit, don't know whether you'll be notified of that; would you look over it? Thank you very much :)